# How to check reputation change for past N days

Tags: discussion, support

I know there is a graph on the profile page of user But that graph shows data for an year approx. So we can not observe the rep for past some days clearly. I also Know there is a detail page [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5055401/inzimam-tariq-it?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2017-11-25%2005:47:27Z) that has options to view rep by post/time/graph But it does not show change in total reputation.

The problem I'm facing is I observed that from past few days when Any user click(Upvote) on my post I see that rep in history and as notification too But It does not increase My total Reputation. Also the Post does not have the increase in upvote count. From the link you can check my [Display back button on action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686555/display-back-button-on-action-bar/37185334#37185334) has +30 reputation in last three days. But not in Total rep & post upvote count.

Anyone know how to check if its not a bug? Or Everything is working fine on `SO`.

Comment: @user0042 Your link is not valid it says "Page Not Found"

Comment: There is a `Reputation` tab if you go to `Activity` in your profile page. Here is the correct [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5055401/inzimam-tariq-it?tab=reputation).

Comment: Yes I know that. As I mentioned in the question that shows only +10, +5 etc. But that does not indicate it changed the total rep too.

Comment: Thanks to @rene for making this post duplicate. This is not the exact duplicate of that question But the answer there has the point required. Here https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I found my solution.